# How to attach eyes to a character's head in Blender with armature and shape keys

Tags: rigify

I have created a puppet character model where the head moves when the mouth opens and closes. The character is rigged with Rigify and I have also added different expressions using Shape Keys. However, I am having trouble attaching the eyes to the head correctly.

I have tried parenting them to the head using "parent to object" and a vertex group of the head, but the eyes move strangely when I move the armature of the body.

Is there a way to attach the eyes to the head so that they follow the mesh both when I move it with the shape keys and with the armature?

I have attached images to help explain the problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do the eyes have armature modifier?

Comment: is the "open mouth" pose done with shape keys or the armature?

Comment: The "open mouth" is done using shape keys and the eyes don't have any modifier. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about joining the eyes to the body/head mesh? Then you can create shape keys for the eyes, too. -- Or use bones for the mouth, maybe?

Comment: Awesome, it worked! I actually gave it a go earlier, but for some reason, the topology of the head got messed up. I figured it might have been because the head mesh had a subdivision modifier and the eyes didn't, but I tried it again and it worked like a charm. Thanks so much for your help!